# get username and mobile from LDAP from a certain group

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ldap, ssms, ldap-query

I need a list of phonenumbers from our AD/LDAP from a certain group for our SMS service.

The problem is that I need to filter on this group to get the phone numbers if this certain users.

The users are in a group/cn with a certain ou. If I search for the group I get this information:

```
''LDAP://CN=<< Groupname of the users need to be selected >>,OU=Programs,OU=Resources,DC=< domainname >,DC=com''
```

Is it possible to get the mobile field of the users of this cn or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Jim,

It helped me in the right direction.

The final solution:

```
SELECT  *  
FROM    OPENQUERY(ADSI,'
                        SELECT telephoneNumber, name
                        FROM ''LDAP://<domainname>.com/ou=accounts,DC=<domainname>,DC=com''
                        WHERE objectCategory = ''Person'' AND objectClass = ''user''
                            AND memberOf=''CN=<groupname>,OU=Programs,OU=Resources,DC=<domainname>,DC=com''
                        ')
```

Comment: i didnt even know you could do an LDAP query with SQL

Answer (score 1):

Something close to:

```
ldap://servername.com:389/OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com?telephoneNumber?sub?(memberof=<< Groupname of the users need to be selected >>,OU=Programs,OU=Resources,DC=< domainname >,DC=com
```

should work.
-jim